# Datasource settings unavailable for dotnetnuke reports module

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7, dotnetnuke-settings

I am running DNN Version 07.02.02.  I am trying to add a reports module to a page, but the settings don't appear to be there.  It was an upgrade, which makes me nervous already and I have specifically installed the same version blank installation on another server and that works perfectly.  I cannot reinstall this installation, as it is somewhat out of my hands and contains much content already.  Attached what I see when I try and go into settings:

[image: Report Settings]

What I am supposed to be seeing under settings is:

[image: Correct]

Instead, what I am seeing is:

[image: Incorrect]

A requirement for reporting module datasource settings is host access, but since I have access to the host menus, I assume I have the required permissions.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you see when clicking on the permissions?

Comment: @tatigo All I see is a list of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is not likely to be encountered, since it is an older version, I did some more digging and would like to provide possible additional things to check.

Accourding to (https://forums.asp.net/t/843862.aspx?Module+Settings+Unavailable+in+Upgrade+to+3+0+11), a possible reason for sections of the menu not displaying was duplicate entries in the PERMISSIONS table.  This does make sense, since this installation was upgraded (and can also be found in cases where the actual module upgrade does not complete as expected).

I will add more, if I find any more possible answers.